# Is there a way to filter a field not containing something in a spark dataframe using scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hopefully I'm stupid and this will be easy.

I have a dataframe containing the columns 'url' and 'referrer'.

I want to extract all the referrers that contain the top level domain 'www.mydomain.com' and 'mydomain.co'.

I can use

```
val filteredDf = unfilteredDf.filter(($"referrer").contains("www.mydomain."))
```

However, this pulls out the url www.google.co.uk search url that also contains my web domain for some reason. Is there a way, using scala in spark, that I can filter out anything with google in it while keeping the correct results I have?

Thanks

Dean

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can negate predicate using either `not` or `!` so all what's left is to add another condition:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.not

df.where($"referrer".contains("www.mydomain.") &&
  not($"referrer".contains("google")))
```

or separate filter:

```
df
 .where($"referrer".contains("www.mydomain."))
 .where(!$"referrer".contains("google"))
```

Comment: It was the !$"referrer" I was looking for. I should have just tried it but the monte carlo approach to coding gets tedious and I couldn't find any documentation about it. Thank you!

Comment: hey! help!, any way to achieve this by comparing to a Column? like $"referrer".contains($"column-that-shouldn't-match")

Comment: @zero323 does this work for specific pyspark version, i am getting 
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.not

DELV_all_cleaned_df2 = DELV_all_cleaned_df.where(not($'DELIV_LOC_DESC'.contains(expr)))
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.not
​
DELV_all_cleaned_df2 = DELV_all_cleaned_df.where(not($'DELIV_LOC_DESC'.contains(expr)))
invalid syntax (<stdin>, line 1)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.not
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I used both df.filter and df.where together and they worked fine, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `Regex`. [Here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch01s07.html) you can find a reference for the usage of regex in Scala. And [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex) you can find some hints about how to create a proper regex for URLs.

Thus in your case you will have something like:

```
val regex = "PUT_YOUR_REGEX_HERE".r // something like (https?|ftp)://www.mydomain.com?(/[^\s]*)? should work
val filteredDf = unfilteredDf.filter(regex.findFirstIn(($"referrer")) match {
    case Some => true
    case None => false
} )
```

This solution requires a bit of work but is the safest one.

Comment: It won't work. If you want to use regular expression you have a few options: 1) `like` with SQL simple regular expression, 2) UDF with standard Scala regex, 3) convert to RDD and filter `Row` objects