# Filtering with Scala and Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have created a unlabeled Dataset which has some columns. The values in one of the Column are France,Germany,France and UK

I know how to filter and count using below code.

```
val b =data.filter(_.contains("France")).count
```

However, I am not sure how to count values other than France.

I tried below code but it is giving me wrong result

```
val a =data.filter(x=>x!="France").count
```

PS: My question is a bit similar to [Is there a way to filter a field not containing something in a spark dataframe using scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33608526/is-there-a-way-to-filter-a-field-not-containing-something-in-a-spark-dataframe-u) but I am looking for some simpler answer.

Comment: How do you know it is not correct? Does it return the number of all records?

Comment: It returns 5 instead of 2

Comment: What is `data` or `_` in this case? You need to check if a particular column of a row in a dataframe is not equal to "France". You shouldn't be checking if a row contains "France".

Comment: `val dir = "/home/test.txt"
val data=sc.textFile(dir)`

Content of test.txt file

M,56,France
F,19,Germany
F,20,France
M,25,UK

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to filter those elements which is equal to "France". 
Try this

```
val a=data.filter(!_.contains("France")).count
```

Answer (score 1):

To cricket_007 's point, should be something like this

```
val myDSCount = data.filter(row => row._1 != "France").count()
```

I am not sure what column your data is in, so the row._1 would change to the correct number.  You can run the following to see all of your columns:

```
 data.printSchema
```