# Drop rows of Spark DataFrame that contain specific value in column using Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I am tryping to drop rows of a spark dataframe which contain a specific value in a specific row.
For example, if i have the following DataFrame, i´d like to drop all rows which have "two" in column "A". So i´d like to drop the rows with index 1 and 2.
I want to do this using Scala 2.11 and Spark 2.4.0.

```
     A      B   C
0    one    0   0
1    two    2   4
2    two    4   8
3    one    6  12
4  three    7  14
```

I tried something like this:

`df = df.filer(_.A != "two")`

or

`df = df.filter(df("A") != "two")`

Anyway both did not work. Any suggestions how that can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df.filter(not($"A".contains("two")))
```

Or if you look for exact match:

```
df.filter(not($"A".equalTo("two")))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that didn´t work for me.

Comment: I edited my answer, filterNot is not standard in scala spark api. Check it. I test it and it works

Comment: Yes you are right, that way it works! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution in a very old post:
[Is there a way to filter a field not containing something in a spark dataframe using scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33608526/is-there-a-way-to-filter-a-field-not-containing-something-in-a-spark-dataframe-u)

The trick which does it is the following:

`df = df.where(!$"A".contains("two")`